# Is maximizing entropy equivalent to minimizing the defined variance?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, information-theory

Assume there is multi-set of some integers : $D = \{a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_{N-1}\}$ such that $\sum_i a_i = A$ we can build a discrete probability distribution by dividing elements of set by $A$, i.e. $p_i = a_i/A$ for $i=1,2,\cdots,N-1$

We define Entropy and Variance as:

Entropy : $H(P) = -\sum_i p_i \log p_i$

Defined variance : $V(P) = \frac1{N-1} \sum_i (p_i - \frac1{N-1})^2$

Is minimizing the defined variance equal to maximizing entropy for this problem? Intuitively the answer is yes since maximum entropy is obtained when the distribution is uniform and the defined variance is minimum when all variables are equal.

Comment: Hint: consider another distribution, with all the probability weights on any one element.

Comment: @Macavity thank you for your hint. I didn't get what you mean, would you mind explaining it to me?

Comment: If all the weight is one one element, variance is zero which is as good as it gets. But entropy is highest.

Comment: @Macavity Actually I've stated in the question what you said in your comment! I'm looking for a proof!

Comment: You mentioned equal weightage to elements probability distribution minimises variance. I showed it doesn't, there is a different distribution which does that. If you can state what exactly you want proved, it may help.

Comment: @Macavity what do you mean by one one element? Would you mind giving an example? The only weighting that leads to minimum variance (zero variance) is equal weighting.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10631/discussion-between-macavity-and-mahdi-khosravi)

Comment: what is allowed to change here? and what is fixed as a constant?

Comment: Yes $A$ and $N$ are fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your statement is confusing because your "variance" is not the variance of the random variable for which the "entropy" is computed, rather it's the mean squared dispersion of the values of the discrete probability function.

<s>With this caveat, the answer is yes, because with the given restrictions, the distribution that maximes entropy is the uniform distribution, which has zero "variance" ... with that special meaning. But this seems rather trivial and not useful.</s>

Update: I'd missed the condition that $a_i$ must be integer. Then (allow me to use $N$ instead of your $N-1$, it feels more natural), I conjecture that the entropy is maximized by the "closest to uniform" distribution: let $u= \lfloor A/N\rfloor$, $n_u = N(u+1)-A$. Then we have $a_i = u$ for $i=1 \cdots n_u$, $a_i = u$ for $i=1 \cdots n_u$,  and $a_i = u+1$ for $i=n_u+1 \cdots N$. Which also minimizes your "variance".

Added: To show that this maximizes the entropy: consider a distribution $\{a_i\}$ where $a_M - a_m >1$ ($a_M, a_m$ are values that attain the maximum and minimum). Show that the process of changing $a_M := a_M -1$, $a_m := a_m+1$ gives other valid distribution with bigger entropy (this can be shown from concavity of the entropy; see also Cover and Thomas, exercise 2.28). Show that repeting this process eventually ends in the distribution given above.

Comment: what if there is not such a distribution available?

i.e. $p_1 = p_2 = \cdots = p_{N-1} = \frac1{N-1} \Rightarrow a_1=a_2=\cdots=a_{N-1} = \frac{A}{N-1} \notin \mathbb Z$

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi So $A$ is fixed but not $a_i$'s?

Comment: @Memming Yes $A$ and $N$ are fixed.

Comment: @leonbloy Thanks. Your solution minimizes variance but does it maximize entropy?why?

Comment: @leonbloy Do you have any starting point to start from? Maybe I could solve it? Thanks again.

Comment: Entropy is concave with respect to the probability. I think you can use this to show that the above has maximum entropy.